# Dummy Variable with increase YEAR

Tags: r

```
dt<- data.frame(year=factor(2000:2004))
```

I need a dummy variable set as below `dt.dummy`,

```
dt.dummy <-matrix(c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow=5)
```

That is, there is no dummy last year,2004 and dummies are created by the increased year.

I will use quarterly data, so atleast 120 observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `model.matrix` to get the dummy coding, and then get the `cumsum` of each column.

```
apply(model.matrix(~year-1, dt)[,-1], 2, cumsum)
```

---

Another option is `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(dt$year)[-1]
#based on the example, we can also change the lower triangle as 1   
d1[lower.tri(d1)] <- 1
```